# PHP - imap/pop3 and Hotmail - Does anybody have working code?

Tags: php, imap, pop3, email-client, hotmail

I'm trying almost 2 days with many different classes and codes to download emails from hotmail but still can't find any working code.

Does anybody have working code that can download emails from hotmail ?

Comment: Forgot my magic 8-ball. Tell us, why is it "not working"?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Hotmail dosen't provide IMAP.

Try to configure your POP client like this:

- POP serveur:

  - `pop3.live.com`
  - port `995`
  - Use SSL
- Account name:

  - `[user]`@`[hotmail|live|...]`.`[tld]` (your Hotmail's mail)
- The password

You can also take a look to [HAIL - The PHP Hotmail Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hail/)

And to this [POP3 e-mail client](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html) under [BSD Licence](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.html) from [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/)

> *But please, can you provide more specifics details about what you are trying to do, **and especially how**. This will help us to helping you...*

Comment: HAIL is giving error:
Login Failure: Error 403: Request was forbidden

Comment: Can you capture the completes headers you send and you receive in return?